# Why is UniswapV2Factory not implementing IUniswapV2Factory 'getPair' function?

Tags: solidity, uniswap

Sorry newb here.
https://etherscan.io/address/0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f#code

Why is there no function called 'getPair' even though IUniswapV2Factory declares it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There's a public mapping called `getPair`. Since it is public a getter is generated with the same name.

```
mapping(address => mapping(address => address)) public getPair;
```

The getter has the same function signature than the function declared in the interface.

```
function getPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external view returns (address pair);
```